# Help Hitler get into art school

Tags: ethics

Edit: Dilemmas or false dichotomy? Being able to refute the dilemma as a false dichotomy is closer to real life than being boxed in with the only given options.

The classic question of killing baby Hitler dilemma e.g. [this](http://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2015/10/killing-baby-hitler-ethics/412273/), how come helping him to get into art school is never mentioned as an option?

Is the question really about choosing between a lesser of two evils or the other alternatives that require time and effort are not mentioned deliberately in order to enable soldiers etc. to be able to live with consequences of taking a life by having a justification? Is this just a way to justify any action by appealing to a greater good fallacy?

Comment: I'm slightly lost as to what you mean by the art school option. I think the point of the thought experiment is would you kill to pre-empt a future full of mass murder (i.e. grave wrong against many)? What does switching that to art school do? (does that stop him from becoming a killer? does that enable him?)

Comment: @virmaior it is well known that hitter tried to get into art school before being rejected and taking the alternative path. Instead killing one or killing many how about a little finess and nobody dies? It is not the dark ages anymore, killing shod not be option to take or not to take , people have to realise there are other choices even in thought experiments so they look for them instead.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Can you improve the headline?

Comment: @JosephWeissman : it is the refutation of classic problem of killing baby Hitler, the question is wrong.the answer by chris sunami explains that trying to make a choice between two morally abhorrent choices, my response is finding an alternative that by-passes having to make an abhorent choice. If the world is gone crazy where lying to the natzi asking for the Jews in the house is a necessity, then shooting the officer in the head and all those that have enforce that reality is just as a valid answer.

Comment: @Arjang can you help me think of a way to phrase the thought-experiment here as a question?

Comment: @JosephWeissman : I need to think about it, I don't know from top of my head. I like what you are suggesting, Initially this was about when to overcome one evil, it has to be replaced with another evil then that means the very system that one is trying to be moral and just within is fundamentally broken.The originl problem is a false dichotomy and it's own assumptions can be used to refute it with this alternative, choosing neither of the evils and applying finesse instead of eye for an eye justification. Similar to Alexanders cutting the knot solution.

Answer (score 4):

The point in dilemmata is the **exclusion of a third way**. *Di* = two, *lemma* = "premise, anything received or taken," from root of *lambanein* = "to take" ([source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dilemma)).

That is something fundamental to (ethical) dilemmata. You could always think of alternatives, but the point is to judge a situation *that is a dilemma*, which is essentially a situation *which cannot be solved in a moral way*.

See for example:

Hare, Richard Mervyn: Moral Thinking. Its Levels, Methods and Point. Oxford/ New York 1981

Donogan, Allan: Consistency in Rationalist Moral Systems. In: The Journal of Philosophy 81.p. 291-309, 1984.

Comment: thank you Philip, sometimes dilemmas are actually false dichotomies, being able to refute the dilemma as a false dichotomy is closer to real life than being boxed in with only the given options.

Comment: @Arjang: Dilemmas, as long as they are only imagined ones, are in some sense *always* false dichotomies, the circumstances are *construed* as dichotomic and by altering the construction, you can always refute the dilemma. That is not the point. The point is that dilemmas are a form of moral (perhaps better: ethical) argument, a situation where you are forced to weigh values. Being closer to real life is pointless here. And more importantly, the hardest dilemma is Sophie's Choice and it has been forcefully established in real life as dillemmatic by Dr. Mengele.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the psychological question of whether to act or remain static with respect to harm and blame, such as in the *Trolley Problem* (or *Train Track Dilemma*), it seems that many folks like to think in black and white. Recent discussions pertaining to terrorists comprise one set of examples relating to whether to kill or let be, ban or accept.

Another important consideration, which is probably more related to ego, beliefs of soul and causality, and ideas of punishment, is that it feels better (emotionally) to put others into categories of good and bad, good and evil, without considering the finer details and factors of causality involved. A person is often seen as either "civil" or "criminal", as if these words really describe a person's value or virtue whatsoever. Hence, if people see Hitler as being "evil", they may feel that any showing of sympathy is intolerable and unbearable. After all, why would you help a "bad" person?

Society would need to accept the idea that causality is complex and that most ill events cannot rightly be blamed wholly on one entity. Furthermore, it is absurd to think that Hitler alone "did" what they say "he did". Leaders are often spoken of as if they personally enacted all the events that unfolded under them. Also, what is to say that there were no pressures on Hitler from others? Could there, for example, have been friends, family, or lovers peer-pressuring him to act in certain ways? Maybe some person or entity was even manipulating him in one way or another. I doubt he was magically impervious to influence from others.

Moreover, Hitler is by no means whatsoever more evil in nature than a relatively large portion of society both then and now. A great many people exist today, who if they were in a position of great power, would do great harm to a great many other people and or things. Taking it even further, imagine putting a 4-year-old child into a position of great power. That would be quite scary indeed. Are 4-year-old children then evil monsters? Well, perhaps, but the point is that society involves interaction, and almost all large-scale events could not have happened without a great many hands at play -- both physically and in terms of social and or financial influence.

Answer (score 3):

Killing baby Hitler, like the [trolley problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem), is part of a general approach to ethics that involves clarifying moral intuitions with the use of thought experiments that pose stark dichotomies.  The general intent is to determine which moral value dominates in a situation where two values are directly opposed.

The reason the Hitler question is never posed in the form you proposed is because it doesn't offer the prerequisite stark choice.  Helping someone get into art school isn't morally abhorrent.

It's a fair question whether this entire approach to ethics is valid or helpful.  As you mentioned, it --by design --precludes a wide range of alternatives, so there's a real sense in which certain moral presuppositions are already included in the experiment itself.  If you accept it as a valid approach, however, then the crafting of a sharp dichotomy is central to the methodology.